# Filemaker ODBC Python Connection issues Mac os 10.12.02

Tags: macos, python-2.7, odbc, pyodbc, filemaker

I'm trying to set up pyodbc on a mac so I can run python scripts to talk to a filemaker database.

I am running python2.7

I have installed ODBC Manager, and the Filemaker odbc client driver. I have tested this connection and it connects fine.

However when I run the python script i get this error

> pyodbc.Error: ('01000', u"[01000] [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib 'FileMaker ODBC' : file not found (0) (SQLDriverConnect)")

```
c = "DRIVER={FileMaker ODBC};SERVER=localhost:2399;DSN=DB;UID=user;PWD=pass;Trusted_Connection=yes" 
con = pyodbc.connect(c)
```

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Make sure the user "user" has ODBC extended privilege in FileMaker

Comment: Thanks, the user is admin and has full access. Unfortunately still the same problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Problem fixed. My odbc.ini file was in the wrong place.

I ran the command

> odbcinst -j

`unixODBC 2.3.5
DRIVERS............: /usr/local/etc/odbcinst.ini
SYSTEM DATA SOURCES: /usr/local/etc/odbc.ini
FILE DATA SOURCES..: /usr/local/etc/ODBCDataSources`

and moved the odbc.ini file from `/Library/ODBC/odbc.ini` to `/usr/local/etc/odbc.ini`

problem solved.

Answer (score 1):

Other options:

PyFileMaker - using XML API
https://github.com/aeguana/PyFileMaker

bBox - plugin
https://bbox.beezwax.net/products/bbox

Python-fmrest - using FM Data API
https://github.com/davidhamann/python-fmrest

Comment: Thanks for these, I will look into them. I'm sure I will be able to get this working though, I had everything i needed running and working on a windows machine and I'm trying to move it all over to a mac.